# Procedural fire - scaling and similar shape on both x and y axis?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, procedural, emission, fire

This is fire, generated as a procedural volumetric shader:

[image]

Viewed from X axis:[image]

from Y axis: [image]

How to get the fire style/shape from x axis to appear on the Y axis as well?

Also, how do I scale up or down this procedural fire without affecting the shape or style of it? Wanna fit it under the cylinder I added later on [in the attached blender file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Pp8bnvmX)

Comment: Hello, Francis, Thanks for the link ... I think it's fair to ask you to give us a clue about _how_ this flame is generated.. (e.g. a node-tree, if relevant?) before asking us to commit to a download.

Comment: Yes, this flame is node generated: https://i.ibb.co/GnXWQM2/kurumii.png

Comment: What you do exactly mean with: _"appear on the Y axis as well"_? Do you want the volumetric effect to be symmetrical in itself?

Comment: Yes, I'd like the Y-axis volumetric effect to appear like how it does on that X-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set these values for the scale, the fire will look the same from both axes.
[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, this worked.

Comment: Also, does anyone know how I can scale this flame without altering the appearance?